# What would be a good approach to secure a STS?

Tags: security, architecture, ws-security, ws-federation

We have implemented a custom STS. Currently, we limit allowed RPs based on realms & hosts that we can configure. This is proving to be slightly unpractical though. I would like to be able to allow people (e.g. our developers) to have access to our auth service, but not allow competitors to use it.

What would be a good approach to implementing some sort of a security mechanism to do this properly? Should I implement some sort of challenge/response mechanism? Or is there something already established as a security practice?

Note, we're using .NET, but I'm sure the solution is agnostic of the technology.